# Running time (using loops and without loops)

Tags: matlab

I want to show running time for two functions.Below you can see two function

```
function example( origimg,t,bwimg )

    imOriginal=imread(origimg);
    tic
    imOriginal=rgb2gray(imOriginal);
    for i=1:size(imOriginal,1)
        for j=1:size(imOriginal,2)
          for k=1:size(imOriginal,3)
              if imOriginal(i,j,k)>t
              imOriginal(i,j,k)=0;
              end
          end
        end
    end  
    figure,imshow(imOriginal);
    toc
    imwrite(imOriginal,bwimg);
end
```

And the other function

```
function example2( origimg,t,bwimg )

    imOriginal=imread(origimg);
    tic
    imOriginal=rgb2gray(imOriginal);
    i = imOriginal>t;
    imOriginal(i)=0;
    figure,imshow(imOriginal);
    toc
    imwrite(imOriginal,bwimg);

end
```

So When I compare  running time of functions, I have encountered a strange result.

Example2's running time is higher than example1's. Where is my fault ?

Comment: try imOriginal((imOriginal>t))=0; What is the size of your array?

Comment: What are the values of your timings? Because if you're seeing only a few microseconds runtime, your image is simply not big enough to do a fair comparison between these two methods...

Answer (score 0):

Factor out all the common code that you don't want to measure:

```
function img = example(img,t)
  for i=1:size(img,1)
    for j=1:size(img,2)
      for k=1:size(img,3)
        if img(i,j,k)>t
          img(i,j,k)=0;  
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

function img = example2(img,t)
  i = img>t;
  img(i)=0;
end

function measure(origimg, t, bwimg, func)
  imOriginal=imread(origimg);
  imOriginal=rgb2gray(imOriginal);
  tic
  imModified = func(imOriginal, t);
  toc
  figure,imshow(imModified);
  imwrite(imModified,bwimg);    
end
```

Then you can compare your two methods with e.g.:

```
measure('inputimg.png', 0.5, 'bwimg.png', @example);    
measure('inputimg.png', 0.5, 'bwimg.png', @example2);
```

If you still don't get a significant difference you should use a larger image, or repeat the code you're profiling (inside tic/toc) in a for loop N times (e.g. 1000 times).

I don't have Matlab at home, so haven't tried any of the code.